# Stop picture element downloading image if viewport over certain width

Tags: css, image, download, responsive

Using a `<picture>` element, what is the best way to stop an image being downloaded if the viewport is over a certain width?

I'm currently using the following HTML and CSS, which correctly prevents `image.png` being downloaded if the viewport is > 900px - **but only when the page is first loaded!** The moment the viewport is resized below 900px and then resized back over 900px again, `transparent.png` is downloaded.

Additionally, on IE9, `transparent.png` gets downloaded when the page first loads *and* when the viewport is resized.

#### HTML

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/png" srcset="image.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
    <img srcset="transparent.png"><!-- 1px transparent PNG -->
</picture>
```

#### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    picture {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I don't want anything to be downloaded above 900px no matter what. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
srcset="data:" OR srcset="about:blank"
```

Also please note the img tag in the picture is loaded first if the media condition is not met on first load otherwise the source image is loaded, so set the img tag to empty and then in the source tag with the media you have load the image you want when the screen is less than 900px. Here is a codepen to check out. reduce the screen size to see the effect.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/rJOwzq

Hope this helps.